Subtract dataframe into subdataframes using pandas
I have large dataframe and I want to substract this dataframe into smaller dataframes based on two conditions. Below is the small a piece of the dataframe:
|          | id             |outcome|
| -------- | -------------- |       | 
|          |1               |   0   |
|    0     |    1           |   1   |
|          |     2          |   1   |
|    0     |     16         |  1    |
|          |      3         |  1    |
|    0     |      5         |   1   |
|          |      4         |  8    |
|    0     |     1          |  1    |
|          |    1           |   1   |
|          |     1          |   1   |
|          |     1          |  1    |
|          |     1          |  1    |
|          |     16         | 1     |

I want to substract this dataframe into smaller dataframes based on Id 16 and outcome 1 then take the row above untill outcome !=1. So to make it clear in the example above I should have two dataframes.
The first one:
|    0     |    1            |   1    |
|          |     2           |   1    |
|    0     |     16          |  1     |

and the second:
|    0     |     1           |  1     |
|          |    1            |    1   |
|          |     1           |   1    |
|          |     1           |  1     |
|          |     1           |  1     |
|          |     16          | 1      |

Thanks in advance.

You could use boolean masks and groupby:
m1 = df['outcome'].eq(1)
m2 = df['id'].eq(16)

m3 = m1.where(m2|~m1).bfill()

out = [g for _, g in df[m3].groupby((~m3).cumsum())]

Output:
[  col  id  outcome
1   0   1        1
2       2        1
3   0  16        1,
   col  id  outcome
7    0   1        1
8        1        1
9        1        1
10       1        1
11       1        1
12      16        1]

Intermediates:
   col  id  outcome     m1     m2     m3  (~m3).cumsum()
0        1        0  False  False  False               1
1    0   1        1   True  False   True               1
2        2        1   True  False   True               1
3    0  16        1   True   True   True               1
4        3        1   True  False  False               2
5    0   5        1   True  False  False               3
6        4        8  False  False  False               4
7    0   1        1   True  False   True               4
8        1        1   True  False   True               4
9        1        1   True  False   True               4
10       1        1   True  False   True               4
11       1        1   True  False   True               4
12      16        1   True   True   True


Hi mozway,
Thanks for the response and sorry for the late respone. Your solution is giving me an empty list. And I dont want it in a list but in seperate small dataframe

@WilliamAshoti then something is wrong with your input. Maybe you have strings and not numbers (in which case you should use '1'/'16' in place of 1/16). My code yields a list of small DataFrames. I have tested or and it works correctly. Please edit your question and provide the output of df.to_dict('tight') where df is your test DataFrame.

Hi Mozway, I have added the following m3 = m1.where(m2|~m1).bfill().fillna(False). Now is working.

also the m2.fillna(False) and m1.fillna(False)
